How to select only specific field in the dropdown from wpf form using c#?
I have a condition that checks if compartment(truck-empty) and purpose("Leaving-Finished Product") these are my only required fields must when selected should along with topseal and bottomseal do a validation and ignore other compartments for validation,  Now the issue now all compartments are seem to be handling this logic and want to prevent it from happening. How can i achieve this?
private void btnSaveTicket_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (txtFullWeight.Text == "" || txtFullWeight.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Capture weight before saving");
            Managers.WeighbridgeLogManager.InsertWBInfoLog("Capture weight before saving", "");
            return;
        }
        if (cbxCompartment.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Compartment", "No compartment selected");
            Managers.WeighbridgeLogManager.InsertWBInfoLog("Please select a Compartment", "");
            return;
        }
        if (cbxCustomer.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Customer", "No customer selected");
            Managers.WeighbridgeLogManager.InsertWBInfoLog("Please select a customer", "");
            return;
        }
        if (cbxProduct.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Product", "No product selected");
            Managers.WeighbridgeLogManager.InsertWBInfoLog("Please select a product", "");
            return;
        }


        if (txtBinsSelected.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Bin", "No Bin selected");
            Managers.WeighbridgeLogManager.InsertWBInfoLog("Please select a Bin", "");
            return;
        }
        if (comboPurpose.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Purpose", "No purpose selected");
            Managers.WeighbridgeLogManager.InsertWBInfoLog("Please select a purpose", "");
            return;
        }
        //if (comboPurpose.Text.ToUpper() != "SELECT A PURPOSE")
        //{
            if (txtFullWeight.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please capture weight", "No Weight entered");
                Managers.WeighbridgeLogManager.InsertWBInfoLog("Please capture weight", "");
                return;
            }


        // Check if the compartment selected is "truck-empty" and the purpose is "Leaving-Finished Product"
        if (cbxCompartment.SelectedItem != null &&
            string.Equals(cbxCompartment.SelectedItem.ToString(), "truck-empty", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            cbxPurpose.SelectedItem != null &&
            string.Equals(cbxPurpose.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Leaving-Finished Product", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        { 
        }
            // Check if both TopSeal and BottomSeal are empty
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTopSeal.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TopSeal cannot be empty when the truck is empty and the purpose is Leaving-Finished Product", "Validation Error");
                txtTopSeal.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBottomSeal.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("BottomSeal cannot be empty when the truck is empty and the purpose is Leaving-Finished Product", "Validation Error");
                txtBottomSeal.Focus();
                return;
            }

        presenter.SaveTicket();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        Managers.WeighbridgeLogManager.InsertWBErrorLog(ex.Message, TripSheetNo.ToString() == "" ? "" : TripSheetNo.ToString(), ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException == null ? "" : ex.InnerException.ToString());
        return;
    }
}


Your if "truck-empty" statement is empty. Maybe you could move the } down to after the txtBottomSeal if, so that the txtTopSeal and txtTopSeal ifs where nested inside the if "truck-empty" ? Btw., you can simplify some code by using Null-conditional operators ?.: With string.Equals(cbxCompartment.SelectedItem?.ToString(), ...) you can drop cbxCompartment.SelectedItem != null &&

@OlivierJacot-Descombes can share full code, so can try and test it on my end and provide responce

You probably have misplaced a brace:
if (cbxCompartment.SelectedItem != null &&
    string.Equals(cbxCompartment.SelectedItem.ToString(), "truck-empty", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    cbxPurpose.SelectedItem != null &&
    string.Equals(cbxPurpose.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Leaving-Finished Product", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{ // This statement block is empty!
} // <=== Move this brace down!

Move the closing brace } to after the other two conditions:
// Check if the compartment selected is "truck-empty" and the purpose is "Leaving-Finished Product"
if (cbxCompartment.SelectedItem != null &&
    string.Equals(cbxCompartment.SelectedItem.ToString(), "truck-empty", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    cbxPurpose.SelectedItem != null &&
    string.Equals(cbxPurpose.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Leaving-Finished Product", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // Check if both TopSeal and BottomSeal are empty
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTopSeal.Text.Trim()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TopSeal cannot be empty when the truck is empty and the purpose is Leaving-Finished Product", "Validation Error");
        txtTopSeal.Focus();
        return;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBottomSeal.Text.Trim()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("BottomSeal cannot be empty when the truck is empty and the purpose is Leaving-Finished Product", "Validation Error");
        txtBottomSeal.Focus();
        return;
    }
} // <=== The brace is here now!
presenter.SaveTicket();


You can also simplify the condition by using Null-conditional operators ?.:
if (String.Equals(cbxCompartment.SelectedItem?.ToString(), "truck-empty", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    String.Equals(cbxPurpose.SelectedItem?.ToString(), "Leaving-Finished Product", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    ...
}

Also, if you added strings to the combo-box then the SelectedItem will be a string as well as the SelectedValue. so you could simply cast it like this:
if (String.Equals((string)cbxCompartment.SelectedValue, "truck-empty", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    String.Equals((string)cbxPurpose.SelectedValue, "Leaving-Finished Product", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    ...
}


let me play around with it. Because had an issue with the second if statement it did not get into but rather hits first if statement and jumps to save which is wrong must cater for an empty topseal and bottomseal when empty then this validation should met the condition
